# I want to know why this is true

Tags: python, operators

```
a = 1 < 2 == 2 > 1 in [1,2,3] < [2,3,4,5] != 1
```

I found this question in a quiz and it's an interesting question. I think that

- first `1<2==2>1 in [1,2,3]` is taken and it's true when I checked
- and then `[1,2,3] < [2,3,4,5]` is taken as true too, and I think it's because of the length
- and at last `[1,2,3] < [2,3,4,5] != 1` is taken and the whole expression is true

Is that correct?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons - the comparisons are _chained_.

Answer (score 1):

The comparisons are chained, so are compared one by one, i.e. `1 < 2`, `2 == 2`, `2 > 1`, etc. It is equivalent to:

```
a = (1 < 2) and (2 == 2) and (2 > 1) and (1 in [1,2,3]) and ([1,2,3] < [2,3,4,5]) and ([2,3,4,5] != 1).
```

Your second point is incorrect as a comparison of lists works per element, so `[1,2,3] < [2,3,4,5]` is `True` because of their first elements, i.e. `1 < 2`.  For example `[1, 2, 3] < [2]` is also `True`.